# Javascript eval error

Tags: javascript

```
try {
    eval(somejavascript);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

gives me runtime errors like

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'leftPad' of undefined
```

Is there any possibility to debug this error, i.e. get the character position/line number where the error occurs in the evaluated expression, and some stack?

The stack I get from chrome ends at eval.

As it goes, I can't put my sample javascript code into a file for debug - the runtime error does not occur if I put the code into a file and include that file in an html document.

Comment: Can you post what's being evalled?

Comment: It seems that you are calling `leftPad` on a variable that is undefined, not initialized. You can replace the `eval` part with the `somejavascript` depending on the value that it has at that stage, maybe a console.log will help with that, in order to help you in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is more about debugging the problem than about the solution.

If so, just wrap the code in a try-catch-statement (for debugging only!):

```
var jscode = 'function baz() { var foo; foo.leftPad(); } baz();';

eval('try { ' + jscode + ' } catch(err) { console.log(err.stack); }');
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fb2y/).